# GNU make to update archive members

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I can't get my GNU Makefile right to maintain an archive with object members.
For now only the first c-file in the directory is compiled.
I have a dir of c-files. This dir contains c-files, makefiles and d-files.
I have two make steps:
step1) generates the d-files (dependency files); this works fine.
step2) should compile c-files that require an update of the associated archive member.
And that step I can't get it right. Only the 1st c-file in dir is compiled and NOT stored in the archive. Below is my Makefile.

```
CFLAGS = -fno-builtin -O2 -mcpu32 -Wall

PWD = $(shell pwd)
XXX = rtems4.11
CPP = m68k-$(XXX)-cpp
CC  = m68k-$(XXX)-gcc
AS  = m68k-$(XXX)-as
LD  = m68k-$(XXX)-ld
SIZE = m68k-$(XXX)-size


# directories for header files
INC=../../../inc
SYS=../../../inc/sys
MNX=../../../inc/minix
INCLUDE=-I$(INC) -I$(SYS) -I$(MNX)

# directory for libraries
LIB=../../../lib
LIBNAM=CONVERSION
ARCHIVE=$(LIB)/lib$(LIBNAM).a


# sources and objects
CSRC=$(wildcard *.c)
OBJS=$(CSRC:.c=.o)
DEPS=$(CSRC:.c=.d)
OBJMBER:=$(foreach OBJ,$(OBJS),$(ARCHIVE)($(OBJ)))


-include $(DEPS)

all: $(ARCHIVE)($(OBJS) $(OBJS)

$(ARCHIVE)(%.o) :
    @echo "Add the archive member $%"
    ar -cvr $(ARCHIVE) $%

%.o: %.c
    @echo "compile $@ from $<"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: You're missing a close paren here: `$(ARCHIVE)($(OBJS)` is that in your real makefile?

Comment: I think you're trying too hard.  Although `make` does support individual archive members as targets and prerequisites, I've never seen a case where using that made much sense.  Personally, I would just make the overall archive depend on all the object files, and provide a rule for (re)building the whole thing at once.  That will be easier to write and maintain, and if there is any performance disadvantage then it surely would be very small relative to managing the archive one object at a time.

Comment: Yes indeed there is a close paren missing, also in the real Makefile. No warning received and/but the variables are filled as expected. The corrected version makes no difference. Same behaviour only the first file in the directory is compiled leaving the object in the same directory. I have the feeling that somehow the desired targets are not connected to the recipes in a proper way.

Comment: In the %o: %.c rule I removed the -o $@ option. The output is not an appropriate format for archiving with ar.

Comment: Further analysis show me that including the dependency files give unexpected behavior. This must be solved first. I raise another question for that aspect

Comment: I have a problem of different nature; nothing to do with makefiles; The directory of source files is on a NAS; Make does not work reliable in that environmnt; After having copied the directories to the destop frontend, makes works as expected. i.e `Don't use a NAS` when developping; at least in my case